# Internet Explorer Specific CSS Glitch

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I seem to have a glitch on in Internet Explorer and wondered if anyone could shed some light

Taking the following page as an example

http://www.flipfilter.com/websites-for-sale

When running in IE not under compatibility mode, all the Cufon (js font replacement) headings disappear. When I click the icon to enable compatibility mode, the pagination seems to go crazy and extends down the page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, specifically as to what causes either of these problems?

If the problem is a validation issue could you point me to which one specifically causes the two errors?

Comment: Cufon is evil. Use `@font-face` which is better and has even wider support - [Font Squirrel even have a generator for it](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Comment: Thanks.I've since made that update and it works a charm. Just have the pagination issue to resolve now!

Comment: Why would you want your site to look good in compatibility mode? This is what users click if the page doesn't look correct. If you page look fine, no user will click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just have the pagination issue to
>   resolve now!

Compatibility mode emulates IE7, so fixing your site to work with it ensures that your site will look acceptable to genuine IE7 users.

You can fix the pagination problem by adding `float: left` to `#pagination-flipfilter li`.

You might also want to adjust the `margin` slightly.